# PHP foreach loop if POST value is not empty

Tags: php, post, foreach, null

I have this `PHP` `loop`:

```
foreach($_POST['af_break_date'] as $id=>$value) {
    $update_break_date_query = "UPDATE studentdates SET student_break_date = '$value' WHERE student_date_id = '$id';";
    $update_break_date_sql = mysql_query($update_break_date_query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

I want to run the `$update_break_date_sql` only if each `$_POST['af_break_date']` **is not** null.

How can this be done?

Comment: there is no such thing as NULL value from postdata as far as I can tell - are those checkboxes you're posting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST['af_break_date'] as $id=>$value)
{
    if($value != '')
    {
        $update_break_date_query = "UPDATE studentdates SET student_break_date = '$value' WHERE student_date_id = '$id';";
        $update_break_date_sql = mysql_query($update_break_date_query) or die(mysql_error());
    }
 }
```

Don't forget to secure for SQL Injection because you are adding raw user input to the query. Have a look at PDO or MySQLi and parameterised queries.

Comment: Thank you! How did I not think of this... Anyway, solved my problem!

Comment: I will, but I have to wait a few minutes to do so.

Answer (score 1):

**use `isset`**

```
if(isset($_POST['af_break_date'] && 
strlen(implode("",$_POST['af_break_date']))>0)
{
....
...
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried that already, but the af_break_date will always POST and then empty data will be sent to the MySQL, I want to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( isset( $_POST['af_break_date'] ) && is_array(  $_POST['af_break_date'] )) {
    foreach($_POST['af_break_date'] as $id=>$value) {
        $update_break_date_query = "UPDATE studentdates SET student_break_date = '$value' WHERE student_date_id = '$id';";
        $update_break_date_sql = mysql_query($update_break_date_query) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use !empty();

For Example

$value = false;

```
isset($value); //return true
!empty($value); //return false
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a condition to check & avoid empty values

```
if($_POST['af_break_date']){
    foreach($_POST['af_break_date'] as $id=>$value) {
      if(!$value) continue;
      $update_break_date_query = "UPDATE studentdates SET student_break_date = '$value' WHERE student_date_id = '$id';";
      $update_break_date_sql = mysql_query($update_break_date_query) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they will be deprecated soon. Instead use mysqli or PDO for connecting database. Use prepared statements to avoid SQL injections and before that do validations before updating datas to database.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to isset is empty which will check if the array is empty, so since its always being posted we check if its empty before running the foreach loop.

```
if (!empty($_POST['af_break_date']) && is_array($_POST['af_break_date'])) {
    foreach($_POST['af_break_date'] as $id=>$value) {
        $update_break_date_sql = mysql_query("UPDATE studentdates SET student_break_date = '$value' WHERE student_date_id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```